# How do we ultimately know Korach was wrong?

Tags: beit-din-court, parshat-korach

As I was learning Maseches Moed Katan Daf 16a, the following question occurred to me (Just in time for the Parsha).

The Gemara in Moed Katan (see https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en ) learns something regarding the laws of Beis Din from the Pesukim by Korach. It's seems to clearly imply that the Dispute between Korach and Moshe was considered a formal "Din Torah" between two parties.

The question is, since Torah Lo Bashamayim Hi (see
https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.59b.5?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=en ), how was the dispute solved by a Miracle i.e., the ground swallowing up Korach...?

I was excited to find this question asked by R' Tzadok Hakohen, albeit without him referencing the Gemara in Moed Katan. You can see his answer here: https://www.sefaria.org/Tzidkat_HaTzadik.64.1?lang=bi

I am looking for other possible answers. Please get involved!

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110736/6592

Comment: @shmosel Regarding Micha Berger's answer on that post (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110742/31919), their long answer seems pretty irrelevant and baseless to me, besides it's quite self-evident that Torah Lo Bashamayim begins right when it's first brought down to earth. That is, when it is all communicated to Moshe on Har Sinai.

And regarding Binyomin's answer there (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/113981/31919), it's helpful to know Tosafos's opinion there, but see my comment challenging the contradiction.

Comment: I wonder if the principle of תורה לא בשמים is that they can't *override* terrestrial halacha. So if there's an open question that can be settled Upstairs, or if it's a dispute that could only be settled by Hashem (as implied in the above gemara), maybe they do have a say.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are adding as it sounds like what I commented there, but I actually just realized that this in itself is a possible path to answering this post's very question! However, that would need to assume that Korach did not have the "Rov".

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read your comment, but yes, it's a similar idea, and yes, I'm saying it could apply here too. I'm not sure Korach's majority or Moshe's greatness would be relevant in a personal dispute, and it's not like there was a greater earthly authority to turn to.

Comment: I will need to look at the sources again, as I think I remember it sounding like most of the leaders of Klal Yisroel backed Korach. As for your terming this a "personal dispute" (which is highly questionable) How exactly do you mean for that to change the rule of Achrei harabim lihatos from applying here?

Comment: If two partners, who happen to be rabbinic authorities, sue a single defendant, can they simply settle the case in their own favor because they're the majority?

Comment: Oh, I see. But that only applies to Korach and Moshe, no? What about all other Sages? Again, assuming most Sages sided with Korach, which please point out if I 'm wrong about.

Comment: I assume those who sided with him did it to share in the benefits (as Korach himself suggested, per Rashi 16:19).

Comment: Firstly, I see Numbers 16:19 does say the whole congregation sided with Korach. Secondly, does alleging vague possible future benefits (which Rashi on that verse might be implying) really disqualify a judge?

Comment: I think the premise of the question maybe is a little faulty. Because the Gemara learns something from a pasuk about Korach that means that the debate between Moshe and Korach was a formal Beis din?? We learn plenty of stuff from let’s say conversations with pharaoh or Nebuchadnezzar, and we don’t consider their convos as official beit dins. We can learn anything from the phraseology of the Torah, no matter the context, because that’s the way Hashem chose to phrase the “plot”, and therefore they’re holy words. Otherwise, obvi we’re not learning Halacha directly from pharaoh’s mouth

Comment: You might be 100% right, I'm just not aware of any more examples like that, can you please reference one or two?

Comment: @AYALTAAROG I mean Idrk the entire Gemara by heart but I’m sure there’s a bunch of places where they quote psukim said by reshaim and learn something from them lol.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this case is different then other “Torah Lo Bashamayim Hi” cases, being that the entire argument (in Beit din) was if moshe always acts only when hashem commands him (in particular appointing Aron)(visit https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.16.11.1, and https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.28 + Rashi on that pasuk)
Therefore a miracle that proves that would provide sufficient proof, and the only possible proof is “Bashamayim Hi”

Comment: Thanks for that interesting answer and welcome to the Community! My main issue with what you're saying is that this is far from the first miracle Moshe performed. What exactly is it that this has over all the earlier miracles? Honestly, I want to point out in your favor that the wording of the verse seems to imply there was something different and extraordinary about this miracle. "V'im Briah Yivrah Hashem..."

Comment: Visit (https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.28) and Rashi. It seems from there that that was the argument

Comment: But After reading https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Foundations_of_the_Torah.8.1 it seems that the argument was not about if he is a Navi, but perhaps just that if when he appointed Aron it was from hashem or not